# Geometry: Construct a rectangle with area equal to a given triangle and with one side equal to a given segment.

Tags: geometry, triangles, rectangles

So we have triangle, ABC, and line segment DE.  We don't know anything about them other than ABC is a triangle of some sort and DE is a line segment.  We're tasked with constructing a rectangle such that its area is equal to that of triangle ABC and one side of said rectangle is equal to that of line segment DE.  I think book one, proposition 44 of Euclid's elements relates to this, but otherwise, I'm not sure how to do this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Take $F$ on the $BC$-line such that $BF=DE$. Take $G$ on the $AB$-line such that $CG\parallel AF$ and let $M$ be the midpoint of $CG$. In the following figure, the depicted rectangle and the triangle $ABC$ have the same area:

[image]

This happens because the area of the rectangle equals the area of $BGF$, and since $\frac{BG}{BA}=\frac{BC}{BF}$,
$$[BGF]=[ABC].$$

Answer (score 0):

I would give an
executive summary like this:

1. Construct a rectangle
   with the same base and area
   as the triangle
   (height = triangle height/2).
2. Construct a square
   with the same area
   as the rectangle
   (from the proof
   of the Pythagorean theorem).
3. Construct a rectangle
   with side DE
   and area the same
   as the square
   (same reason).

Done.